# New/Modified files won't inherit group ownership

Tags: magento2, apache, file-permissions, centos, linux

This is happening for the first time after months of developing. I don't know what changed.

We set file permissions and then We run in Magento2 root folder:

```
sudo chown -R user:apache .
```

But, every time We run commands like.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
composer install
composer update
```

and every time some of the users in apache group modifies any file We get that file changes to user:user group. So, nobody else in apache group can access files (neither apache itself, so naturally website breaks).

How can I set to keep :apache as group owner?

**EDIT:**

So, I followed this instructions and was able to get modified files to keep the apache group ownership: https://serverfault.com/questions/46886/linux-losing-group-ownership-of-files but still the new **uploaded** files by different users are owned by user:user instead of user:apache. How could  I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically had to follow this instructions: https://serverfault.com/questions/46886/linux-losing-group-ownership-of-files

Which lead me to run following commands:

```
chgrp apache /var/www/html/magento2
chmod g+ws /var/www/html/magento2
```

And following command to set all folders to inherit the same previous command:

```
find /var/www/html/magento2 -type d -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod g+ws
```